# Large Excel File - Upload and Import - Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

all

I want to upload and import a large excel files having more than one million records in to my Java program.

I can easily import small files using Apache POI in to my system , but when i starts with large files application throws and out of memory error,

**i searched google and found many threads on so , i tried everything but could not get around of this.**

can anybody give me solution for my particular problem, import time is not an issue for me, right now also i can bear with performance issue as well,

just want to import this data in to my existing  system without oem error.

**I have very good configuration on my system and java has enough memory to use so hardware is not an issue.**

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem and the POI API is just a memory hog. Easiest thing is top open the excel as a zip file, and then parse the sheet with a SAX parser

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to stream the data so that you don't need to store all the records in memory at once. POI does support streaming (see [XSSF and SAX event API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)). As you read the data, ship it off to wherever you need to (database or wherever, you did not specify) -- with the streaming API you should not read all the data into memory before processing it.

You could also export the data to a CSV file, and then use a regular `FileInputStream` to read the file and process each record as it is read.

Comment: hi already used SXSSF , it can write only , when i try to read with it it gives me all blank values from cell.

Comment: Right, sorry, I edited the answer to point to XSSF. Can you export to CSV though? That would probably be a lot simpler.