# Increase request timeout of browser for form submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I'm trying to upload a excel Sheet using multi-part form upload and apache-poi java. Its working fine in chrome browser but in IE and FF its keeping on loading and not returning back to page even after inserting all the records, if i upload a file more than 1 mb. Is there any way i increase my browser timeout using java script.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some piece of code. I think there must be some browser specific UI code written to handle the response that is running only in chrome. see this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360220/large-excel-file-upload-and-import-java

Comment: No there is no such thing, its just a simple form and my maximum records are 10k. And the above thread says to use fileinputstream and i'm using that already.

Comment: How you are getting response from the server ,is it a simple http response? check in firebug of mozilla like what  response in coming after insertion and see if any error is there on front end.

Comment: The response just keeps on loading and is pending.But the records are inserted in database but not returning to browser

Comment: Have you seen it in Firebug what is the response content and for sake print response on servlet then it will be more clear to

Comment: Please check the screen shot my response i attached

Comment: the screen shot shows the request is being aborted , in case of chrome how much time its generally taking for the response to come.

Comment: and in if you can print the response on servlet itself that will also allow you see the status of response